# Counting valid Binary Sudoku boards

Tags: code-golf, binary, sudoku

Sequel of [Counting valid Binary Sudoku rows](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/201094/78410).

### Background

Binary Sudoku, also known as [Takuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuzu), Binario, and Tic-Tac-Logic, is a puzzle where the objective is to fill a rectangular grid with two symbols (0s and 1s for this challenge) under the following constraints:

1. **Each row/column cannot have a substring of `000` or `111`, i.e. one symbol cannot appear three times in a row, horizontally or vertically.**

   - A row/column of `1 0 0 0 1 1` violates this rule since it contains three copies of `0` in a row.
2. **Each row/column should contain exactly as many 0s as 1s, i.e. the counts of two symbols must be the same.**

   - A row/column of `1 0 1 1 0 1` violates this rule since it has four 1s but only two 0s.
   - Some examples of rows that meet the first two requirements include:

     ```
     [1 0 0 1]
     [1 1 0 0]
     [1 1 0 1 0 0]
     [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
     ```
3. **The entire grid cannot have two identical rows or columns.**

Note that the constraint 2 enforces the grid size to be even in both dimensions.

Here are some examples of completed Binary Sudoku:

```
(4x4)
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1

(6x8)
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

### Challenge

Given two positive integer `m` and `n`, calculate the number of distinct valid Binary Sudoku boards of width `2m` and height `2n`. (You may take the values of `2m` and `2n` as input instead of `m` and `n`.)

[A253316](http://oeis.org/A253316) is the sequence for square boards.

### Test cases

```
m,n => answer
-------------
1,1 => 2
1,2 => 0
2,2 => 72
2,3 => 96
2,4 => 0
3,3 => 4140
3,4 => 51744
3,5 => 392208
4,4 => 4111116
```

For the input `1,2`, it counts 2-by-4 boards, i.e. boards with four rows of length 2. But we can't have four distinct rows of length 2 to fill the grid (we have only 01 and 10). Therefore, by rule 3, the answer to the input `1,2` is zero. The same argument applies to the input `2,4` (4-by-8 boards).

[Reference implementation in Python](https://tio.run/##jZLBboMwDIbveQrfSFjXlWyTJtTsRRCaGA1dJEiyEFStL89soKWqdtiFWPb3278T/E/8claOYxNcBybqEJ1rezCddyGmLICCZ1bj95UFd@oxKLrKc2PjBj6N5UYUMi@358a0LZdpEAIaF8CAsRAqe9T8JU3D09sG6BRgmkW2rd1gI0@yRCgVoLIHSHa7XQLWRRLP1JzPsuwuX7Kuih/fgx40WSrKkt2NrVMpcgZg9WnlSkwQh2Iirz0InCuE46JTH9x3LgDZvqmgLofa2WjsoFei1ZZjScC7AnlRTpUKLyfbq37oeO1asVdyGoYxtTsbT7riUZYbmIIMg2WeEPm6w7byXtsD0fAAxYKUYpml217/j769vSvPfMB3BXJJhi9ularv3aa05vw4tHSvI1/TKMAf4c97FuP4Cw). This can handle up to `3,5` in a minute. Note that putting `r > c` takes much more time than the same pair swapped, though the results are the same.

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest submission in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we take `2n` and `2m` as input instead of `n` and `m`?

Comment: @RGS Yes. I'll edit the post to allow it.

Comment: `4,5 => 201005480`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>265</s> <s>250</s> 198 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:sum(not(n>len({*s})or m>len(set(z:=[*zip(*s)]))or any(p*3in"".join(v)or v.count("1")*2-len(v)for p in'01'for v in[*s]+z))for s in P(*[[*P(*['01']*m)]]*n))
from itertools import*;P=product
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3NjsIwDITvPEXUC7ZhEX9CK1bdZ@BecijQiqDGjpK0EkU8e0m4jGb8zcjuGe/Cu1/np7Y8T11tL7da8dIeQ2@BJQL/dw3Di8IbxSv7TaGJMB7LikbjgAJqzKzmJzjaGS6K1UMMw5Cvw@oqPUcoNgXS9ifPB2wTcMrwfL2ZZz8kX1HQixG/LKSsTkBVRVlzTZNFrYkRZ60Xq0xsfBTpUtU68ZH@TqXzcuuvcXLepI8t7JcHxOkD) Takes as input `2n` and `2m`. Thanks to Bubbler for finding a bug in my original answer and for golfing a *massive* 52 bytes off.

### How it works:

The anonymous function we define will be taking `2n` and `2m` as input, generate all binary boards with the specified dimensions and then count how many of those satisfy the restrictions.

#### Generating all boards

```python
... for s in P(*[[*P(*['01']*m)]]*n))
from itertools import*;P=product
```

is generating all the boards. The `product` function from the library `itertools` can be used to generate the cartesian product of all the arguments it is given. Breaking the nested `P`s down, `P(*['01']*m)` creates a list of length `m` with `'01'`: `['01', '01', ..., '01']` and then the splat operator `*` is used to turn each element of the list into an argument to `P`, so `P(*['01']*m)` [generates all valid rows of length `m`](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgDADQ2Z6im8Ik0cFouAO7cfITSYQ2tQ6eHn3z41dPyt3AUkpCjz3AIZQw6i5KdN0YE5OonYJnoe1ZFYL7Y2jsXLeuXmwycJAgY8wY3AgVS8zasCnlAw). Call it `P1`.

Then we have `P(*[[*P1]]*n)` which takes all valid rows and turns it into a list of all valid rows, with `[*P1]`. We then enclose such a list in another list and multiply by `n`, so that we get a list of length `n` where each value is a list of all valid rows. Then the splat operator `*` is used to provide such a list as a series of arguments to the `itertools.product` function, thus [getting all the correct-sized binary sudoku boards](https://tio.run/##PYwxDsIwDEV3n8JbG08kMCBQ7@C9ylRARCKxZczA6UMG1OXr6enp69ef0o5ntd4rLniCNjYBPEwqFr@bi7zeWKqKOV15UZPbZ3PgOEKeaZ0OccpUA3D6m5U45kwtjBsxVCwNOV0AUa00nzXsGHr/AQ). We iterate over those with `s`.

#### Checking restrictions on the board

Now we are left with checking the conditions imposed on the board `s` with

```python
not(n>len({*s})or m>len(set(z:=[*zip(*s)]))or any(p*3in"".join(v)or v.count("1")*2-len(v)for p in'01'for v in[*s]+z))
```

Instead of verifying if the board satisfies everything, we check if the board doesn't violate any restriction:

- `n>len({*s})or m>len(set(z:=[*zip(*s)]))` checks if there are `n` unique rows, by converting the list of rows into a set; similarly we transpose `s` into `z` and check if there are `m` unique columns;
- then `any(B1 or B2 for v in[*s]+z)` goes over all rows and all columns:

  - `B2 = v.count("1")*2-len(v)` gives 0 when the amount of `1`s is exactly half of the size of the row/column and other non-zero integers when it is not. Regardless of giving a positive or negative result, [Python will treat it as a Truthy value](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0zBViEns7hEIzexQKO4pEhHIdpQRwGODIAoVlOTKzNNoUwvOb80r0RDyVBJU8tINyc1T6NM04pLQaGgKBMkHJKfr5CbmFepXwJkpKWWKxgWK2lyceG0wACOKLHg/38A).
  - `B1 = p*3in"".join(v) for p in'01'` builds the substrings `"000"` and `"111"` and checks if those are in the row/column

#### Wrapping it up

In the end, we just sum all the Truthy values that correspond to all the boards that did not violate any restrictions.

Comment: I think `v.count("1")==m/2` must be `v.count("1")==len(v)/2` because the length of `v` can be either `2n` or `2m`.

Comment: @Bubbler I think you are right!

Comment: [198 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY3NjsIwDITvPEXUC7ZhEX9CK1bdZ@BecijQiqDGjpK0EkU8e0m4jGb8zcjuGe/Cu1/np7Y8T11tL7da8dIeQ2@BJQL/dw3Di8IbxSv7TaGJMB7LikbjgAJqzKzmJzjaGS6K1UMMw5Cvw@oqPUcoNgXS9ifPB2wTcMrwfL2ZZz8kX1HQixG/LKSsTkBVRVlzTZNFrYkRZ60Xq0xsfBTpUtU68ZH@TqXzcuuvcXLepI8t7JcHxOkD) by logic negation, `('0','1')->'01'`, and abusing `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 144 bytes

*Input (2n,2m)*

```
(l=Length)@Select[Tuples[{0,1},g=#],And@@Flatten[{#~Count~1==#~Count~0,Max[l/@Split@#]<3}&/@Flatten[c={#,Transpose@#},1],1]&&l/@(Union/@c)==g&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctBC4IwGIDhvxIMhsJAJY8NFkGngkA7jR3GGmswP0U/IRjzry8vBe/hvTyDxrcdNHqjs@O5CPxmweG7FJ0N1qDs1ynYRcaaNYk5ThQ7w0uIa9CIFmQk22VcAbeG89/W7K4/MlSim4JHQdTpmGj1J4ZHwvpZwzKNixUksUbtUbqL4gl@hEqYknNHFc2P2QMehJOxZW1SOX8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
IIP;S¬$PȧQƑ
×Ø-ṗ$s€ÇƇZ€$⁺L
```

A dyadic Link accepting `2n` on the left and `2m` on the right (or vice-versa as it's symmetric) which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/TM8A6@NAalYATywOPTeQ6PP3wDN2HO6erFD9qWnO4/Vh7FJBWedS4y@f///8m/00A)** This will time out even for `(6,4)` (i.e. `m=2` and `n=3`)*

#### How?

I imagine that if one worked out a combinatorial formula it would be much shorter (and quicker and more memory efficient!), but this entry is pure brute-force...

```
IIP;S¬$PȧQƑ - Link 1, (    no row has a run of 3 or more
                       AND no column contains differing type counts
                       AND all the rows are different
                      ): a single board, B
I           - incremental differences (vectorises) - e.g. [-1,1,1,1] -> [2,0,0]
 I          - incremental differences (vectorises)
  P         - product - this will give a list which will contain a zero for any row
                        containing a run of at least three equal items
     $      - last two links as a monad:
    S       -   sum (vectorises) - since we use -1 and 1: zero if the counts are equal
     ¬      -   logical NOT
   ;        - concatenate
       P    - product - this will be non-zero if (no row has a run of 3 or more
                                  AND no column contains differing type counts)
          Ƒ - is (B) invariant under:
         Q  -   de-duplication - i.e are all the rows different?
        ȧ   - logical AND

×Ø-ṗ$s€ÇƇZ€$⁺L - Link: 2n, 2m
×              - multiply -> 2n×2m (size of board)
    $          - last two links as a monad:
 Ø-            -   signs = [-1,1]
   ṗ           - Cartesian power (all lists of length 2n×2m of items -1 and 1)
      €        - for each:
     s         -   split into slices of length 2m (i.e. into rows)
           $   - last two links as a monad:
        Ƈ      -   filter keep those for which:
       Ç       -     call last Link (1) as a monad
          €    -   for each:
         Z     -     transpose
            ⁺  - repeat the last link - i.e. check the results with rows<->columns
             L - length
```

---

* I ran `m=2`, `n=3` locally and it yielded `96` as expected (after over an hour in which it hit 100% memory (16GB Ram) and slowed to a snail's pace while using disk).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>102</s> <s>81</s> 64 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔×θＮη≔ＥＸ²η⪪⭆◧⍘ι²ηΣλθζＦ²≔ＥΦζ⬤κ›⁼№μ0№μ1⁺⊖№κμΣＥ²№μ×³ＩξＥθ⭆κ§ξμζＩＬζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDdboQgEIXv@xQTr4aEJq3du72yv9lk25hsX4Aqq6SACkO78eUtuDbKBQnnnPlmhqoVruqEnqaD7QN9BPMlHQ5sf1N4rxqLn8pIjwOHrc8Yh3bNvIsey@43GnnSOZx6rQhP5JRtZlPUR3kmfBReXlVUHHK2pINBnZBDusbIPXcOMGew4b8qTbHByKHQGr85vDkpkvIyBKE9PnXBEhoO2V0WKevzPkvUUgePz7Jy0khLsl7ykWPYMkLqkm8qr5s/REV4wgtbDocUjB@yrhcpBR1sLS94mYH/e5QxQTjXH6VtqMUxevtp2sFuuv3Rfw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the actual size as input. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ≔×θＮη
```

Input the width and area.

```
≔ＥＸ²η⪪⭆◧⍘ι²ηΣλθζ
```

Generate all possible grids of `0`s and `1`s of the given width and area.

```
Ｆ²
```

Loop over rows and columns.

```
Φζ⬤κ›⁼№μ0№μ1⁺⊖№κμΣＥ²№μ×³Ｉξ
```

Keep only those grids where each row has an equal number of `0`s and `1`s, is unique, and contains neither `000` nor `111`.

```
≔Ｅ...Ｅθ⭆κ§ξμζ
```

Transpose the rows and columns so that the columns can be checked on the next pass.

```
ＩＬζ
```

Output the number of remaining grids.

Previous much faster 102-byte version:

```
ＮθＮη≔ΦＥＸ²θ⭆◧⍘ι²θΣλ›⁼№ι0№ι1ΣＥ²№ι×³Ｉλζ⊞υ⟦⟧ＦυＦ‹ＬιηＦζＦ¬№ιλ⊞υ⁺ι⟦λ⟧ＩＬΦＥΦυ⁼ＬιηＥθ⭆ι§νλ⬤ι›⁼№λ0№λ1⁺⊖№ιλΣＥ²№λ×³Ｉν
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNT8MwDL3zK6KeHKlIUHbbqXxq0pgqwW3aIbRZG8lN13wA2p8vThdYi5ZDYj@/PNuvbIQpO4HDsNIH7za@/ZAGer68muYN5bm1qtbwrNAR8ioOUHRfFGUp63nK3pxRuh5hUa3l3sG9sPKEgkpZxiPPt4CcU/RipAhST70XaOGh89oFZnKTUPWc3iY8/gvq2aT0rlpp4Y4QYd2oykflI41beNuAT9l2R8m@Mww8Z@O7ltbSpWvXgCJ2w2PhGN9N587TBFX2K1agtwHc4o6HHrQcUUPzqDdxJ4b0Ky44b5myQOqnxpFw7la6kt@gT42JlSOGwkWzcG4W/pk1zvkoSyNbqZ2sZutc8BL/e6n55CyHYcEWw/Un/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the actual size as input.